# Name of Google Chrome dinosaur cactus game

Tags: game-identification, google-chrome

What is the name of the Easter egg within Google Chrome that's available when you're offline?

[image: Screenshot of game]

It involves controlling a T rex which is trying to jump over cacti.

Comment: It's a little game that Google made up to put in Google Chrome. That is what it is called.

Comment: Still, "Google Chrome Dinosaur Cactus Game" sounds great as a title for it.

Comment: https://www.blog.google/products/chrome/chrome-dino/ didn't give an obvious name for the game.

Comment: At Google IO, I spoke with the Dinosaur and its keeper one night, and they mentioned the Dinosaur's actual name was "Melissa".

Nice that they have the full screen game with chrome://dino url now

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's sometimes called the downasaur. I don't know if it was originally his name, but some google folks seem to call it that way nowadays :D

See here:
https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/

Reliable - Load instantly and never show the **downasaur**, even in uncertain network conditions.

Answer (score 21):

It is simply called [T-Rex or T-Rex Runner in the source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/52.0.2742.0/components/neterror/resources/offline.js), and doesn't seem to have an official name. As it is an Easter Egg, it is likely it will never get one unless or until it is officially acknowledged. [The patch](https://codereview.chromium.org/545973003/) with this change also doesn't seem to name it, it simply refers to a bug which is not available to view.

Answer (score -8):

I think the name is Chrome Jump because their is an app based off of it and that is called Chrome Jump.

Comment: Searching google for "Chrome Jump" returned no relevant  results.