# What's the deal with the cake in T-Rex Runner (Downasaur)?

Tags: downasaur

My internet went off for a little so naturally I played a bit of [T-Rex Runner](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/202180) ([Downasaur](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/311636)) to pass the time but got surprised with something I have never seen before when playing it, a cake.

It looked like a power up or a mushroom from Super Mario, it gave me a party hat and there were gray ballons flying in the background but unfortunately no extra life.

What's the reason for it to be added, I'm guessing it wasn't just a random improve of the game, is it to celebrate some birthday? Is there anything else I missed or is it just for visuals and does it matter if I jump over it and don't catch it?

Notably after getting the cake the hat stood through the rounds until I refreshed the page.

[image: Cake, hat and ballon in the game (day and night)]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It marks the tenth anniversary of the release of the browser 10 years ago.

See [this blog post from Google Chrome’s blog](https://www.blog.google/perspectives/rahul-roy-chowdhury/happy-10th-birthday-chrome-best-yet-come/) on September 4, 2018.

> We launched Google Chrome 10 years ago to give...

As well as this one: [As the Chrome dino runs, we caught up with the Googlers who built it](https://www.blog.google/products/chrome/chrome-dino/)

> You currently have a special edition of the game out. Can you tell us
>   more about that? Alan: Over the years, the game got a few upgrades,
>   like pterodactyls and night mode. The latest one rolled out this week:
>   a special “anniversary edition” for Chrome’s 10th birthday. Look out
>   for cake, balloons, and a fancy birthday hat.

Answer (score 4):

[Downasaur turned 10 this year](https://9to5google.com/2018/09/04/google-celebrates-chrome-10-offline-dino-game/) and the cake is there to celebrate that:

> Back in 2008, Google Chrome was revealed to the world via a comic book that detailed the new open source browser. To mark its 10th anniversary this month, Google has updated and themed the whimsical Offline Dino Game.
>   [...]
>   The birthday edition allows the dinosaur to collect a birthday cake and wear a party hat, while the background features balloons. This easter egg will be themed for the entire month of September.

Comment: From [one of the comments](https://9to5google.com/2018/09/04/google-celebrates-chrome-10-offline-dino-game/#comment-4076612638) I found out that I could play it with a higher resolution no matter if I'm connected to the internet or not by going to chrome://dino/ and also tested what happens if I jump over the cake (it keeps spawning more).

Answer (score -3):

It's for the celebration of the tenth year of chrome, but a disadvantage of the cake is the party hat. It stops you from ducking under mid level birds.